# How to include jar in SOLR

Tags: user-interface, solr, velocity

I am trying to include a functionality in solr velocity UI Wherein I have included a export button and on clicking it the highlighted results has to be stored in external file for which I have developed a Servlet Which does this exporting work So i have a doubt how to  include this jar in SOLR velocity UI. And how to invoke it on clicking of export button through AJAX.
Thankyou.

Comment: Do you have the source code of the solr..?

Comment: yes i do have solr source code

Comment: did you tried by adding the same in velocity/lib folder...after that you have build the solr...

Comment: yes i have added and on click of export button  i have specified the servlet name is that the correct way will it be able to recognize the class??

Comment: did you build the code the code...and checked for any compilation issue..?

Comment: yes there is no compilation issue

Comment: So you aren't able to see it in the ui...?